# Ember #each get each element from an array NOT the whole array each time?

Tags: jquery, arrays, binding, ember.js

I have an Ember Object defined that gets it's data from a .json file.

I am using ember and x-handlebars to output images from an array that has been defined as part of an Ember Object using an Ember array controller.

The array is defined as follows :

```
{
     "gallery_small": ["data/images/gallery_01_small.jpg", "data/images/gallery_02_small.jpg"]  
}
```

And my current html is :

```
{{#each content.gallery_small}}
     {{#collection contentBinding="Application.projectdetailController"}}
          {{content.gallery_small}}
     {{/collection}}
{{/each}}
```

What is currently being outputted is

```
data/images/gallery_01_small.jpg,data/images/gallery_02_small.jpg
data/images/gallery_01_small.jpg,data/images/gallery_02_small.jpg
```

**What I want is**

```
data/images/gallery_01_small.jpg
data/images/gallery_02_small.jpg
```

How can I go about getting this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

By doing `{{#collection contentBinding="Application.projectdetailController"}}` you are defining a new context. So in {{content.gallery_small}} the content is an object of Application.projectdetailController, wich seems to be the array.

I would try this:

```
{{#each image in Application.projectdetailController.content}}
    {{image}}
{{/each}}
```

If it does not work, please update your question with your full code, or create a jsfiddle, so I could better understand what is the problem.